# Using Windows UWP Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.SerialDevice from Universal Class library

Tags: c#, serial-port, win-universal-app, class-library, windows-10-iot-core

I'm making a Modbus library (again...). This time it is meant to run on Windows 10 IoT Core.

I've encountered an interesting problem.
This chunk of code:

```
string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

var port = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);

if (port != null) {
    port.BaudRate = 9600;
    port.DataBits = 8;
    port.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
    port.Parity = SerialParity.None;
    port.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;
    port.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
    port.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
}
```

1. Used from within a Universal App works perfectly. Of course if you add following code to Package.appxmanifest:

   ```
   <Capabilities>
        <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
            <Device Id="any">
                <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
            </Device>
        </DeviceCapability>
    </Capabilities>
   ```
2. Used from within Universal Class Library (File -> New Project -> ... -> Windows -> Universal -> Class Library (Universal Windows) in VS2015) creates Null Reference Exception from mscorlib.dll, which is same as if you remove DeviceCapability from Universal app's Package.appxmanifest.

I suspect that this behaviour has something to do with Class Library not having manifest file and therefore not having appropriate permissions.

Can I use Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication from within class libraries?

Is Microsoft making me tell the users 'Hey! I made for you a useless library for which you have to implement transport layer by yourself in any of your applications separately.' ?

Comment: Does it work on desktop?

Comment: @danvy Same thing. I've checked if it's using a correct device and it turned out that device ID is exactly the same in both cases (class lib and app). Only one, single difference is that above piece of code is placed in class library or directly in app. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Did you ever finish this library? I'm looking for an UWP library too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a Universal app project and a Universal Class Library using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 on Windows 10 10586. I setup the app manifest, put the SerialDevice code in the librairie and call it from the app.

It works.

Be careful if your code is called twice, you might get a null reference exception as port2 will be null.

```
var aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
var port = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);
Debug.WriteLIne(port?.PortName);
var aqs2 = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var dis2 = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
var port2 = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);
//port2 will be null
Debug.WriteLine(port2?.PortName);
```

Comment: Indeed it was called twice - in all mess of porting old code to new platform I overlooked it. That's really a shame. I am so, SO happy that it was my fault. Thank you for your help and have a nice day.

Comment: Why can not windows return PortName in 2nd time ? I want to make a button to show PortName list. then, I want to call 2,3,4 time or more...  Please advice me..