# UWP , Device COM port number is NULL in 2nd call SerialDevice.FromIdAsync

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, serial-port

To get COM port number ( serial, ex : COM1,COM2,,, )
When clicking a button, I want to show available COM Port list on UI. First click success to get COM numbers, but 2nd click failed. Do you have any reason ?

Here is a simple code to test two click.

```
public async Task<bool> test()
{

    Debug.WriteLine("Start");

    var aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
    var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
    var port = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);
    Debug.WriteLine("COM=" + port?.PortName);
    var aqs2 = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
    var dis2 = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs2);
    var port2 = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis2[0].Id);
    //port2 will be null
    Debug.WriteLine("COM=" + port2?.PortName);

    Debug.WriteLine("end");

    return true;
}

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Task.Run(() => this.test()).Wait();
}
```

and Package.appxmanifext has this code.

```
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
        <Device Id="any">
            <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
        </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

and here is executed result.

```
Start
COM=COM15
COM=
end
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234217/using-windows-uwp-windows-devices-serialcommunication-serialdevice-from-universa/34245439) also point out same issue. I wrote comment at here. but To get answer, I post this as New question.

**Q : To get COM port list and update list when device is changed, What code should I write ?**

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
var aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
var port = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);
Debug.WriteLine("COM=" + port?.PortName);
var aqs2 = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var dis2 = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
var port2 = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);
Debug.WriteLine("COM="+port2?.PortName);
```

I think you meant to have:

```
.....
var aqs2 = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var dis2 = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs2);
var port2 = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis2[0].Id);
Debug.WriteLine("COM="+port2?.PortName);
```

Comment: : )  You are right , hehe.. sorry, my test app was wrong ..  ... but Result was same...  I revised my above code.

Answer (score 0):

[With this article,](http://www.otl.uk/2016/09/14/uwp-serial-port/) I added Dispose() between 1st and 2nd calling.
Now, I get expected result.

I thought "SerialDevice.FromIdAsync" mean Open Serial ports.
then, 2nd access return null.
then I tried to close it before re-opening...

```
public async Task<bool> test()
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("Start");

            var aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
            var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
            var port = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);
            Debug.WriteLine("COM=" + port?.PortName);

            //closing device...
            port.Dispose();
            port = null;

            var aqs2 = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
            var dis2 = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs2);
            var port2 = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis2[0].Id);
            //port2 will be null
            Debug.WriteLine("COM="+port2?.PortName);

            Debug.WriteLine("end");

            return true;
        }
```

and here is result ( I expected ).

```
Start
COM=COM15
COM=COM15
end
```

in UWP application, There is no Open serial method.
When is it the timing to open ? Is "SerialDevice.FromIdAsync" ??

**Another Question**

Is there any way to know "COM port number" without opening device ?
without "SerialDevice.FromIdAsync" ?
because I just want to make drop down menu of COM1,COM2,COM3....

**Update 1:**

I found a [good example for UWP + Serial.](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess)
I will learn it : )